# Get image file path from resources

Tags: c#, console-application

I have an image file `day.jpg` in `Resources` folder  and I want to access it in the code as `string path` not as `byte[] img`

Here's what I have tried.

```
string dayWallpaper = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + @"..\..\Resources\day.jpg";
// Didn't found it
```

```
string dayWallpaper = Resource.day;
// Outputs byte[] and gives me an error
```

Then I tried to convert the `byte[]` to `String` didn't work as well

```
static byte[] SliceMe(byte[]? source, int pos)
{
   byte[]? destfoo = new byte[source.Length - pos];
   Array.Copy(source, pos, destfoo, 0, destfoo.Length);
   return destfoo;
}

static string ByteToPath(path)
{
   String file = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(SliceMe(path, 24)).TrimEnd("\0".ToCharArray());
   return file
}
```

Outputs black screen

Later I search for the file

```
if (File.Exists(dayWallpaper))
{
   do stuff
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("File does not exists");
}
```

And gives me the else statement.

Comment: why you would want to convert?

Comment: If the image file is in the "Resources" folder, does that mean that it is an embedded resource in your project? The "Resources" folder is typically NOT deployed with an assembly.

Comment: The whole point of resources is that they are not discrete files. They are data compiled into the EXE or DLL itself. There is no path because there is no file. You should spend some time to learn how resources work.

Comment: You would have to select the 'copy to output folder' in the resource properties if you want to access the resource from a file path.

Comment: The thing is that I want to store the image in a folder in the executable and the user could add more images later on. How do I do that, as what I've read so far, using resources is not the right way to go for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the answer you posted to your question, the fact that your relative path works is an "accident" that would fail on any other device deploying your app because without the existence of the source code project the path doesn't exist. One good option is to mark the `day.jpg` file as `Copy to Output Directory` at which point most installer bundlers will pick it up and deploy it in your setup.exe, msi etc. If you are specifically using the Visual Studio IDE, you would do it like this:

[image: Copy if Newer option]

Now, at runtime, to acquire the path to the copied file:

```
var srce = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Resources", "day.jpg");
```

However, there is more work to be done, because you state that you "want to store the image in a folder in the executable and *the user could add more images later on*." The present location of the file is not suitable for that purpose, so I would recommend the additional step of creating an AppData entry for the user to store their created content.

```
// Obtain a folder that "the user could add to later on".
var appData =     
    Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
        typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Name
    );
Directory.CreateDirectory(appData);
```

Since you mention wanting to store the `day.jpg` image in that folder, go ahead and copy it to the AppData location (if not already there from a previous run of your app).

```
var dest = Path.Combine(appData, "day.jpg");

// Copy the image (if it's not there already) into folder that the user can add to.
if (!File.Exists(dest))
{
    File.Copy(
        sourceFileName: srce,
        destFileName: dest
    );
}
```

Alternatively, you could set the BuildAction to `EmbeddedResource` and manipulate the file as a byte stream and achieve the same end result.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it this way

```
string resourcePath = Path.GetFullPath(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + @"\..\..\..\..\Resources");

string dayWallpaper = resourcePath + @"\day.jpg";
```